# How do I convert a byte[] to date

Tags: java, mysql, date

I m working with mysql and java Jtable

In one case i can only get from the JTable a byte [] representing a date.

I could not find a way to convert the byte [] back to a date.

I built this code in order to simulate the problem:

```
public demoJFrame1() {
    try {
        setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        String select = "SELECT validity_start_date FROM `Table`  ";
        Connection c = ObtainConnection();

        java.sql.ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(select);

        if (rs.next()){
            Date dt = rs.getDate(1);
            byte[] byteArr = rs.getBytes(1);
        }

        // if i only have access to the byte[] byteArr, how do i convert it to Date variable ????

    } catch (java.sql.SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(demoJFrame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public final Connection ObtainConnection() throws SQLException{
        String DBurl       = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBname";
        String DBdriver    = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String DBlogin     = "root";
        String DBpassword  = "pass";

        Class.forName(DBdriver);
        return java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DBurl, DBlogin, DBpassword);
}
```

If I only have access to the byte[] byteArr, how do I convert it to Date ?

Comment: String s = Arrays.toString(byteArray);
then convert 's' to date...
I recommend jodatime libraries. Or you can use Calendar class

Comment: I don't understand why you can't get the Date by using JDBC. Does `rs.getDate(1);` fail? Do you know why?

Comment: Hey , thanks for your unswer, the reason i can not use getDate function is because i am overriding function `Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int rowIndex, int vColIndex)` on `javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer`, this only gives Object value variable , and not the resultSet it self.

Answer (score 1):

Shan , Tried your solution, but it gave me an error. 
see, the conversion of `Arrays.toString(byteArr)` returns int value rather than chars. So this is the solution that worked for me:

```
String s = new String((byte[])value);
d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

`String s = Arrays.toString(byteArr);` then convert 's' to date...

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").parse(s);
```

or you can use  I recommend jodatime library...